# Can questions be deleted if they spread misinformation?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, site-policies

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124398/triple-hit-abilities) has a false premise. It states as a matter of fact that certain abilities can hit an enemy 3 times while they are designed to hit at most twice. However, because I found this to be very unlikely, I asked for the evidence that the OP claims exists. After a lengthy discussion in the comment section, the OP failed to deliver any evidence of the claimed behavior despite repeated, unbacked assurances that it does exist. The final nail in his argumentative coffin was that he asked me and another infidel to research and verify *his* premise, because he had to go to sleep now, even though he supposedly had the evidence at his fingertips.

Ordinarily I wouldn't make a fuss about it, because people being wrong on the internet is just the way of things. However, the fact of the matter is that, for better or worse, SE sites often rank pretty high on Google as they are intended to, and indeed, that question is already the top result (after videos) for "draven ult triple hit".

As evidenced by the initial responses to my first comment, it doesn't take much more than a boldly worded statement to elevate speculation and misinformation to truth. This I find unacceptable out of principle, so I believe that question and others like it should be deleted such that Google can not find them any more.

Comment: I don't believe these questions should be deleted (by moderators, since AFAIK they are the only ones who can delete questions other than the OP), but you *can* downvote them, for not being useful (as per the downvote tooltip - "it is unclear or not useful")

Comment: Generally, an answer should address the fallacy, and prove it's not possible.  We do tend to get lots of questions where the asker has misunderstood a mechanic, and it's up to the answers to set them straight.

Comment: @fbueckert this!  Part of what we do here is solve problems, and if the problem is the validity of the question (from a logic standpoint, not on-topic or close-worthiness standpoint), then that's the problem we should solve.  Other people may have the same misconceptions, and would thus be helped in the future by this first person being corrected.

Comment: @Hackworth But the video clearly shows the 3 hits if you look closely, while blitzcranks pull does a little damage you can see that aswell. And with you citing proof of another champion with a whole different mechanic doesn't disprove that the ult can't tripple hit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We quite often get questions where the asker doesn't quite understand something, and is basing their question off that mistaken assumption.  Part of our expertise in cases like this is addressing the misunderstanding, and pointing out how it actually works.

If we delete questions that spread misinformation, we're not really helping the internet, other than leaving it alone.  To do the internet a solid, we should be proving or disproving their claim.  And how do we *really* know it's misinformation?  Deletion is a rather big step to take, and shouldn't be taken lightly.

That's what should be done in this case.  Research this possibility, and provide your proof.  Whether it's false or not is immaterial; your proof will bear out what happens.